# Converter exercise: Skips if and else if statements

Tags: c++, converters

I was trying to make a converter where user will first write a temperature and then choose to which measurement they want to convert.
If I write a number computer skips the if and else if statements and it shows "Wrong Selection" and loops again.
I want it to use functions in if statements and loop again until the user prompt 'q' or 'Q'.
Thank you in advance.

My code looks as follows:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double fahrenheit_temperature {};

double fahrenheit_to_celsius (double fahrenheit_temperature);
double fahrenheit_to_kelvin (double fahrenheit_temperature);


double fahrenheit_to_celsius (double temperature)
{
    cout << fahrenheit_temperature << " in fahrenheit is: ";
    return round((5.0/9.0)*(fahrenheit_temperature - 32));
    cout << endl;
}
double fahrenheit_to_kelvin (double temperature)
{
    cout << fahrenheit_temperature << " in fahrenheit is: ";
    return round((5.0/9.0)*(fahrenheit_temperature - 32) + 273);
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char selection {};
    while ((selection != 'q') || (selection != 'Q'))
    {
        cout << "Enter temperature in fahrenheit: ";
        if (!(cin >> fahrenheit_temperature))
        {
            cerr << "This is not a number!";
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nConvert to Celcius (write C or c) or Kelvin (write K or k)?";
            cout << "\nIf you want to quit write q or Q" << endl;

            if ((selection == 'C') || (selection == 'c'))
            {
                fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit_temperature);
            }
            else if ((selection == 'K') || (selection == 'k'))
            {
                fahrenheit_to_kelvin(fahrenheit_temperature);
            }
            else if ((selection == 'Q') || (selection == 'q'))
            {
                cout << "Thank you for using our superduper converter.";
                break;
            }
            else
                cout << "Wrong selection" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Thank you for using our superduper converter.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you reading into `selection`?

Comment: This type of problem means you did not step through the code with a debugger. If you had a debugger and knew how to use it (to step through the code line by line looking at the variables on each step) you would have seen the bug in less time then it took you to post this question. I am saying this to urge you to spend some time and learn to use your debugger. It's a tool I still use as a professional developer nearly daily.

Comment: Why do people keep claiming that C++ "skips" statements randomly? You can rule that out and instead focus on your own logic.

Comment: See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`, so you can convert the input to a single case and make only one comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the cin for your selection variable

```
else
{
   cout << "\nConvert to Celcius (write C or c) or Kelvin (write K or k)?";
   cout << "\nIf you want to quit write q or Q" << endl;
     
   cin >> selection;

   // if-statements
}
```